# Cordova - FileTransfer - gives me a NOT_FOUND_ERR

Tags: android, cordova

I'm writing a small app to download statistics from a connected object (an Air Purifier... )

I want to download files from a web server down to a mobile phone (Android for now).

Doing so, I get a NOT_FOUND_ERR; but the file does exist on the web server, and it does not exist new on my mobile phone.

(This may help: when I create a directory, it does not fall in the Android/com.air_serenity.appli/files  nor /cache  directories. I just don't see where it is created. But it does exist, because I cannot create it twice by relaunching the app. I decided to fortget this non-blocking error, but it may be linked with my current issue.)

I'm using the latest Cordova version, with the relevant plugins (File and FileTransfer).

Here is the code:

```
function onDeviceReady() {  
    window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
    if (localStore) window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota(PERSISTENT, 1024*1024*10, function(grantedBytes) {
        window.requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);
        }, fail);
}

function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    // creating a directory does work. 
    // I can also create a file in the directory. I cannot see where the file is created, but I cannot create it twice, which means that it is somewhere...
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory('3JLGRJD', {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(dirEntry2){
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        var uri = encodeURI('http://www.air-serenity.science/cache/3/J/L/G/R/J/D.air');
        fileTransfer.download(uri, dirEntry2.fullPath + 'D.air',
            function(entry) {alert("ok");},
            fail,
            {}
        );
    }, fail );
}

function fail(evt) {alert('Error: ' + evt.code);}
```

Can anyone help me to find what is missing?
Thanks so much!